# Tkinter text widget is wider than any other widget with grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

From tutorials, I have kind of been under the impression that grid just "kind of figures it out" for width, but it's clearly not the case when it comes to Text (I suppose when combined with list).

With the following code, listbox has is tiny and Text is absolutely massive (Width wise). I can make the listbox equal to the size of the Text by changing sticky="ew", but that's not what I want - I want a reasonable, equivalently styled "grid".

If I hardcode the size of the width, it's even more frustrating, because listbox width seems to equate to approximately 2/3 of Text width.

I've read up on rowconfigure and columnconfiugre, but this seems to actually do nothing with the below code (note - rowconfigure and columnconfigure are not in the below code, but I have tried them, perhaps I'm using them wrong).

Anyways, with the below code - can anyone explain to me how to make these more reasonably sized width wise, and also the same? Should I hardcode a width to Text and then set listbox to sticky="ew"? Seems counter intuitive to the grid layout concept.

```
class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self.frame = tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):

        self.lst_bx = tk.Listbox(self.parent, height = 15)
        self.lst_bx.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=(10,10), sticky="w")

        self.exe_field = tk.Text(self.parent, height=15)
        self.exe_field.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=(10,10), sticky="w")

        self.pick_exe_btn = tk.Button(
            self.parent, text="Choose Location", width=15
        )
        self.pick_exe_btn.grid(row=0, column=2)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    #window_config(root)
    MainApplication(root).grid(stick="nesw")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.mainloop()
```

I'm sorry for being such a noob, I swear I have searched this a lot before posting here - I just cannot find a straight answer on why ListBox is a completely different width from Text (and even moreso when I specify a width).

Comment: To get a reasonable, equivalently styled "grid", create frames and put the widgets inside frames. Use `rowspan`, `columnspan` and `sticky parameters properly. It will take some time, complexity will depend on what kind of UI you are trying to implement.

Comment: @Abhijeetk431 Do you have an example of how to do this?

Comment: BTW: First: `__init__` always returns `None` so there is no sense to assign to self.frame - you can use `self` to get access to this frame. Second: `self.parent` keeps `root` so you put widgets directly in `root`, not in frame `MainApplication`. Use `self` to put widgets inside frame `MainApplication`. Third: `Listbox` and `Text` can use different font and tkinter calculates real width using `width=` and font size.

Comment: I think what you want is unclear, Text widget seems to be in its default size. If you want to decrease its width, then configure `width`?

Comment: Perhaps provide an image on what you want the GUI to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The how tkinter calculates the dimensions tkinter.ListBox() and tkinter.Text() widgets is a little bit different from most of other widgets where it uses pixels. For these 2 specific widgets, the width is calculated in terms of characters whereas the height is assessed in terms of lines.

1. You did not set the width of `self.lst_bx`, so tkinter sets it by default to 20 characters.
2. You did not specify the width of `self.exe_field` either. So tkinter calculates this width based on the current default font size.

From 1) and 2) we can conclude that it is quite normal we can not expect from `self.exe_field` to have the same width as `self.lst_bx`. This means, you have no option other than hard coding them and visually check the GUI.

With minor changes of your code (mainly provided in the comments below your question) this is how I solved your issue:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.lst_bx = tk.Listbox(self, height = 15, width=70)
        self.lst_bx.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(10,10), sticky="w")

        self.exe_field = tk.Text(self, height=15, width=80)
        self.exe_field.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(10,10), sticky="w")

        self.pick_exe_btn = tk.Button(self, text="Choose Location", width=15)
        self.pick_exe_btn.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    #window_config(root)
    MainApplication(root).grid(stick="nesw")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.mainloop()
```

Note where I moved the `columnspace` option (it quite does not make a sens in the two places where you have set it previously). Note also that tkinter calculate the character somehow differently between the listbox and text widgets. Depending your operating system (and maybe machine also), you may have to change the 2 width dimensions I set to the widgets in questions.

Here is what I got on **my** machine:

[image]